# Как сделать так чтобы два identifier выполнялись отдельно?

Tags: objective-c

Вот пример кода:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

OMAllAbonementTableViewCell *cellAbonement = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:abonementIdentifier];
OMVIPAbonementTableViewCell *cellVIPAbonement = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:vipabonementIdentifier];

if (!cellAbonement) {

    cellAbonement =
    [[OMAllAbonementTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:abonementIdentifier];
}

OMAbonement *abonement = (OMAbonement *)self.allBenefit[indexPath.row];
cellAbonement.benefitAbonementImage.image = abonement.photo;
cellAbonement.benefitAbonementLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", abonement.name, abonement.surname];

if (!cellVIPAbonement) {

    cellVIPAbonement =
    [[OMVIPAbonementTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:vipabonementIdentifier];

}

OMVIPAbonement *vipabonement = (OMVIPAbonement *)self.allBenefit[indexPath.row];
cellVIPAbonement.benefitVIPAbonementImage.image = vipabonement.photo;
cellVIPAbonement.benefitVIPAbonementLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vipabonement.name];

return cellVIPAbonement;
return cellAbonement;
```

}

Comment: вам надо на основе indexPath выбирать какой identifier вам нужен и работать с ним

Comment: Можно по подробнее а то у меня что-то не очень получается)

Comment: а какой критерий для cells? на основании чего должна быть одна или вторая?

Comment: Есть массив с элементами двух классов. Одна cell должна отражать элементы одного класса а другая другое. Это можно так делать?.

Comment: ну это не сложно. как классы называются?

Comment: OMAbonement; OMVIPAbonement;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не проверял, но вроде должно работать

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if([self.allBenefit[indexPath.row] isMemberOfClass:[OMAbonement class]]) {
        OMAllAbonementTableViewCell *cellAbonement = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:abonementIdentifier];

        if (!cellAbonement) {

            cellAbonement = [[OMAllAbonementTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:abonementIdentifier];
        }

        OMAbonement *abonement = (OMAbonement *)self.allBenefit[indexPath.row];
        cellAbonement.benefitAbonementImage.image = abonement.photo;
        cellAbonement.benefitAbonementLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", abonement.name, abonement.surname];

        return cellAbonement;
    }

    if([self.allBenefit[indexPath.row] isMemberOfClass:[OMVIPAbonement class]]) {

        OMVIPAbonementTableViewCell *cellVIPAbonement = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:vipabonementIdentifier];


        if (!cellVIPAbonement) {

            cellVIPAbonement =
            [[OMVIPAbonementTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:vipabonementIdentifier];

        }

        OMVIPAbonement *vipabonement = (OMVIPAbonement *)self.allBenefit[indexPath.row];
        cellVIPAbonement.benefitVIPAbonementImage.image = vipabonement.photo;
        cellVIPAbonement.benefitVIPAbonementLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", vipabonement.name];

        return cellVIPAbonement;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) Все работает))). Очень классное решение)